# spy on Observable.filter

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs, observable

I have a Jasmin test in which I wish to check if the `filter` function on an `Observable` has been called

It looks something like this:

```
const spy = spyOn(component.myObservable,'filter');

mySubject.next(data);

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

and the implementation :

```
this.myObservable
 .filter(data => data.....)
 .subscribe(date => data....)
```

I know that is't been called, but still I can't get the check to work.

**Update**

By using `do` i can see that the Observable catches the event. This tells me that the code works and that it is a matter of testing it right

```
this.myObservable
 .do(data => console.log(data) // log: 3
 .filter(data => data.....)
 .subscribe(date => data....)
```

Comment: Why? I would check if subscribe works properly and set data in your component.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Could you add that if any

Comment: Please post all relevant code, not just snippets that you considered important (you considered them wrong, because if they were working as you expect, the test would pass). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . *the implementation* - where was it called? Usually you need to spy on `filter` and `subscribe` **callbacks**, not `filter` and `subscribe` themselves.

Comment: @ Volodymyr Bilyachat if the `filter`is suppose to evaluate to false, it would never reach the subscribe

Comment: @ Surender Kherwa no exceptions